# SQL aliasing with FROM AS

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, alias, relational-division

```
SELECT A.barName AS BarName1, B.barName AS BarName2
FROM (
    SELECT Sells.barName, COUNT(barName) AS count
    FROM Sells
    GROUP BY barName
) AS A, B
WHERE A.count = B.count
```

I'm trying to do a self join on this table that I created, but I'm not sure how to alias the table twice in this format (i.e. FROM AS). Unfortunately, this is a school assignment where I can't create any new tables. Anyone have experience with this syntax?

edit: For clarification I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4. The schema for the tables I'm dealing with are as follows:

- Drinkers(*name*, *addr*, hobby, frequent)
- Bars(*name*, addr, owner)
- Beers(*name*, brewer, alcohol)
- Drinks(*drinkerName*, *drinkerAddr*, *beerName*, rating)
- Sells(*barName*, *beerName*, price, discount)
- Favorites(*drinkerName*, *drinkerAddr*, *barName*, beerName, season)

Again, this is for a school assignment, so I'm given read-only access to the above tables.

What I'm trying to find is pairs of bars (Name1, Name2) that sell the same set of drinks. My thinking in doing the above was to try and find pairs of bars that sell the same number of drinks, then list the names and drinks side by side (BarName1, Drink1, BarName2, Drink2) to try and compare if they are indeed the same set.

Comment: @imotl3 Which table you want to use twice?

Comment: This is not a self join. This is an implicit join between a derived table (the inner select statement) and a table called B.

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi the derived table within the FROM parens

Comment: @ZoharPeled I guess what I'd like to accomplish is a self join between the derived table and itself..? Sorry, very new to SQL

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? Please edit your question to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Exact same set? I mean, if bar A sells beers 1, 2, 3, and bar B sells beers 1,2,4, should you return A and B, or only if both sells exactly the same beers (1,2,3 and 1,2,3)?

Comment: Postgres 8.4 has been unmaintained and unsupported for a long time. You should really plan an upgrade to a supported version (at least 9.6 or 10.0)

Comment: Note:I added the relational-division tag. Please click on the tag to find similar questions and answers.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned what RDBMS you use. 
If Oracle or MS SQL, you can do something like this (I use my sample data table, but you can try it with your tables):

```
create table some_data (
  parent_id int,
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);

insert into some_data values(1, 2, 'val1');
insert into some_data values(2, 3, 'val2');
insert into some_data values(3, 4, 'val3');

with data as (
select * from some_data 
)
select * 
from data d1 
left join data d2 on d1.parent_id = d2.id
```

In your case this query

```
SELECT Sells.barName, COUNT(barName) AS count
FROM Sells
GROUP BY barName
```

should be placed in WITH section and referenced from main query 2 times as A and B.

Comment: sorry, I added a lot more clarification to my original post. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: The query is pretty correct in Postgres too. And it enables a self-join of generated dataset.

Comment: Common Table Expressions are supported by most popular rdbms platforms except MySQL which will do that in version 8.x (at time of this comment) see [this availability table](http://modern-sql.com/feature/with)

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly unclear what you are trying to achive. Are you looking for a list bar names, with how many times they appear in the table? If so, there are a couple ways you could do this. Firstly:

```
SELECT SellsA.barName AS BarName1, SellsB.count AS Count
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT barName
    FROM Sells 
) SellsA
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Sells.barName, COUNT(barName) AS count
    FROM Sells
    GROUP BY barName
) AS SellsB
ON SellsA.barName = SellsB.barName
```

Secondly, if you are using MSSQL:

```
SELECT barNamr, MAX(rn) AS Count
FROM
(
SELECT  barName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDR BY barName PARTITION BY barName) as rn
FROM Sells
) CountSells
GROUP BY barName
```

Thirdly, you could avoid a self-join in MSSQL, by using `OVER()`:

```
SELECT
        barName
        COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY barName PARTITION BY barName) AS Count
FROM Sells
```